# HikariCP pool is overflowing Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, hikaricp

I have a service for Spring Boot and I get an error when working with the database and rest.

`spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5`

When an application sends a rest request to another service and the service responds with a delay (eg timeout) at this time, HikariCP will continue to hold the connection.

An example I address from three threads take something from the base and put it in rest and simulate the delay

`Thread.sleep(10000);`

`restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);`

As a result, I get

`HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=5, active=3, idle=2, waiting=0)`

if there are more than 5 threads I get an error.
How best to solve the problem, set up rest to less wait or somehow close the HikariCP connection

Comment: Does this call happen inside a `@Transactional` method? Do you use also JPA?

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak no, this method without ```@Transactional``` annotation but there is ```@EnableTransactionManagement``` annotation
 over main class and yes i am using jpa

Comment: property spring.jpa.open-in-view = false in application.properties helps to solve this problem Hikari no longer holds connection

How correct is this solution to the problem?